# Unable to set certificate friendly name through PowerShell (access is denied)

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to update a (root) certificate's friendly name through PowerShell.

The certificate I'm trying to update is highlighted in the screenshot below (taken from `certmgr.msc`):

[image: certmgr.msc]

Here's the PowerShell code  (largely taken from [here](http://vanhybrid.com/2013/01/20/updating-the-friendlyname-property-of-a-certificate-using-powershell/)):

```
Set-Location cert:
cd .\CurrentUser\Root
$cert = gci .\02FAF3E291435468607857694DF5E45B68851868
$cert.FriendlyName = "UserTrust CA"
```

*(I've verified the thumbprint with the certificate properties in certmgr.msc to make sure it's the same certificate).*

The last line will result in the following error:

```
Exception setting "FriendlyName": "Access is denied.
"
At line:1 char:7
+ $cert. <<<< FriendlyName = "UserTrust CA"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

I've tried the following things so far:

- Running PowerShell as administrator
- Changing the execution policy using: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Other information:

- PowerShell version is 2.0 (running on Windows 7 Enterprise x64)
- I'm running the x64 version of PS
- DEP and UAC are disabled
- My account is part of the Administrators group
- I'm a complete PowerShell n00b ;-)

PS version output:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: Didn't work for me either, even though certmgr does this without any problem. I have tried opening the certificate store with explicit read/write permissions from PS, but that did not help either. I have found the error is probably returned by the CertSetCertificateContextProperty() API and that's pretty much all I have.

Comment: If you could easily change the properties of a certificate after it were created it'd defeat the purpose.  You'll need to reissue the certificate or create a new one in memory.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I'm able to change the friendly name property without any issue using `certmgr.msc`. So I fail to see how this should be different in PowerShell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your version of Powershell to `3.0` or `4.0`.
See [Get-ChildItem for Certificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847761(v=wps.620).aspx)

I have Powershell 4.0 and I was able to change the FriendlyName without problems. This was visible in `certmgr.msc` after a restart.

You can download Powershell 4.0 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855).

If you are a Powershell beginner it's probably better to use `Get-ChildItem` instead of `gci` for improved readability. Also, `cd` is an alias of `Set-Location` so it's better to choose one or the other in your script to avoid confusion.